# Adding Navigation Controller to existing UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to both Objective-C and the iPhone SDK in general, so please bear with the noob question.

I've successfully implemented a table view with an array for the title, subtitle and cell icon and it's working out great. What I'd like to do is load a PDF file depending on which cell is selected and I understand that a Web View seems to be the best option?

I've hit a block, I can't add a navigation controller to the existing table view in the xib file (I started as a single view application) and everything that I'm reading around the interwebs is suggesting starting out in a different way. Either I'm doing something completely wrong or I've missed something entirely.

So is there anyway that I can implement this Navigation Controller and Web View with what I currently have or am I going to have to start again, copying and pasting various bits of code?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers.

Matt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a XIB file that represents a `UITableView`, then what you should be able to do is:

1) When presenting your `UITableView`:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewCon = ...; // Load it from the XIB file
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewCon];
// Present the navCon, however you're currently presenting your table view
```

2) In your `UITableView`, when a cell is pressed:

```
WebView *webView = ...; // Create the web view, and also load a URL
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have MyAppViewController.xib, created when the project was created. I get the second part but not the first, where should it be going?

Comment: Well it depends on what is in MyAppViewController - how are you creating your window and "launching" your UI? I think it would help if you posted some additional code in your question - maybe add code from your app delegate (where I'm guessing the window is created, and a subview is being added.)

Comment: I've got it, the code you gave me sent me in the right direction and it's sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewrite your app. You cannot add navigation view to table view. The right pattern for your task is to start with navigation view controller as a root of your app and define your table view controller as a root controller for the navigation controller. Then, when the user selects some row in the table you should push a web view to your navigation controller.

refer for the UINavigationViewController class reference.

Comment: If it was to be re-written, what type of project should it be?